# in a form tag the input show [object Object] at first render instead of placeholder (it use the value attribute)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

This is the BookForm.js it is a component that use react context api , this component return a form that contain of 3 input tag

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { BookContext } from '../contexts/BookContext';
/* ________________________________________________________________ */
const BookForm = () => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(BookContext);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(BookContext);
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState(BookContext);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(title, author);
    dispatch({ type: 'ADD_BOOK', book: { title, author } });
    // addBook(title, author);
    setTitle('');
    setAuthor('');
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="book title"
        value={title}
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        required
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="author"
        value={author}
        onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
        required
      />
      <input type="submit" value="add book" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default BookForm;
```

The output is
[image: This is the output view]

the below codebox is BookContext.js that is a stateless function for providing book data and dispatch function and there is a useEffect hook to storing data of new books :

```
import React, { useReducer, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { bookReducer } from '../reducers/bookReducer';
/* ________________________________________________________________ */
export const BookContext = createContext();
/* ________________________________________________________________ */
const BookContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [books, dispatch] = useReducer(bookReducer, [], () => {
    const localData = localStorage.getItem('books');
    return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
    localStorage.getItem('books');
  }, [books]);
  /* ________________________________________________________________ */
  return (
    <BookContext.Provider value={{ books, dispatch }}>
      {props.children}
    </BookContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default BookContextProvider;
```

Comment: Do not format normal text as quotes -> [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I'm going to assume that `const [title, setTitle] = useState(BookContext);` and ` const [author, setAuthor] = useState(BookContext);` are objects. So their initial state is being set as the value of the inputs. Resulting in your `[object,object]`

Comment: @RyanZeelie yes exactly

Comment: I personally would use Zustand for state management. It's just a much easier and more intuitive lib in my opinion

Comment: If I dont wrong, you get a object value from your server and you should get your value from Bookcontex forexample: value ={bookcontex.title } , for being helpful please  log Bookcontex in your useEffect and add result in your question .So that I can solve your question better

Comment: @Mohsen.RJ you are right and for more information I've tried to import all state as follow:   const [books,setBook] = useState(BookContext)  and it works but there is a problem and it's  deleting of previous input from input box, it doesn't work, I mean this part     setTitle('');             
            setAuthor('');                  
I have used    value={books.title}  and     value={books.author}  that solved my problem but create a new one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.